# Simplified formula for calculating sum of $\binom{n_1}{r_1} \cdot \binom{n_2}{r_2} + \cdots$.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Is there any formula for calculating the following expression ?

Given the relation $N = r_1 + r_2$ and $r_1$ is only odd and $n_1$ and $n_2$ are positive integers, we need to calculate value of:
$$\binom{n_1}{r_1} \cdot \binom{n_2}{r_2} + \binom{n_1}{r_1+2} \cdot \binom{n_2}{r_2-2} + \binom{n_1}{r_1+4} \cdot \binom{n_2}{r_2-4} + \binom{n_1}{r_1+6} \cdot \binom{n_2}{r_2-6} + \cdots$$

It is given that initial value of $r_1 = 1$ and $r_2 = N-r_1$. Series continues until either $r_1=n_1$ or $r_2<0$.

Is there a simple formula for calculating above ?
Anything in terms of power of $2$ would be highly appreciated

link to related problem: https://www.codechef.com/FEB21B/problems/SUMXOR2

Comment: Since the sum doesn't also involve $r_1-2,r_2+2$, etc. (i.e. terms going to the left until they can't), it is asymmetrical, which suggests there isn't an explicit formula. (For comparison, truncating the terms of the binomial theorem at an arbitrary term won't have an explicit formula.)

Comment: @runway44 but they are increasing and decreasing at width of 2
$$\binom{15}{1} \cdot \binom{10}{9} + \binom{15}{3} \cdot \binom{10}{7} + \binom{15}{5} \cdot \binom{10}{5} + \cdots$$

Comment: The question was asked more than 10 times in the last two days. Could you explain?

Comment: Incrementing/decrementing by 2 doesn't change the fact it's truncated at an arbitrary term, OP.

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, its related to programming ;), I asked on stack overflow but they closed it saying ask on Maths one
It's not related to any ongoing contest though

Comment: There is not any problem similar to this one, I asked this because in my program, It's being used. 
You can assume the problem is :
Given n1 boys and n2 girls, in how many ways can a group of N people be selected, such that there are always odd number of boys? Given n1+n2>=N

Comment: Don't you find it very surprising, that  so many completely new users ask the same question with interval of several minutes?

Comment: @user The actual question is quite different and its not related to this one, They all asked this because they thought it could be simplified in O(1) complexity but now I'm sure there is nothing like that, I might have to think another approach to problem

Comment: Does this mean that you all solve the same problem, which is however not an ongoing contest? What is this problem?

Comment: @user https://www.codechef.com/FEB21B/problems/SUMXOR2/

This is the original problem

Comment: Thank you! If you add this information into the question body as a motivation part I will upvote.

Comment: @user yes, did that