# Vandermonde's Convolution for odd terms

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

We know from the [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), that:

$\displaystyle \large {m+n \choose r}=\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}$

I want to find the sum of only those terms where $k$ is odd. What's the closed form of that? If there's no closed form, what's the simplest possible simplification of the sum?

Comment: Where is the problem from? Why do you want to solve it? We've been seeing many similar problems recently.

Comment: It looks similar to this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013315/combinatorics-that-looks-similar-to-vandermondes-identity); you might want to take a look at it.

Comment: Read the comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021439. Are you solving the same problem from `codechef.com`?