# Sum of sum of odd terms of Vandermonde's Identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

The [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) tells us:

$\displaystyle \large {m+n \choose r}=\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}$

However, I want to find out the closed form or the simplest form of the expression:

$\displaystyle \large \sum_{r=1}^{p}\sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}$, where $p$ is a natural number.

But I only want to include the terms with **odd** $k$ to be included in the **inner sum** (the $\displaystyle \large \sum_{k=0}^r{m \choose k}{n \choose r-k}$ one)

I had previously posted a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4022197) before, but I couldn't get a simplification for that case. However, with a change in the nature of the sum I believe will render it to have a simplification, at least this time.

Comment: It should be $2^{m+n}-1$.

Comment: You have already asked the same question some hours ago https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4022197 !!!

Comment: Read the comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4021439. Are you solving the same problem from `codechef.com`?

Comment: @ZAhmed sorry I meant $p$ instead of $m + n$, I've edited the question, can you look at it now?

Comment: @JeanMarie this is a different question, but sure *interpolates* with it.

Comment: There isn't any formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{p} {q \choose k}$, if $p=q$ it equals $2^p-1.$

Comment: @ZAhmed but if I want to consider only the odd terms (where $k$ is odd) of the inner sum, even then is there no simplification possible?

Comment: I acknowledge the difference, but you should have, in such a case, begun by a reference to the related cousin question.

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm new to this website, so I'm sorry about that. I'm updating my post with a reference to the aforementioned post.

Comment: You did not answer my question (which I ask the second time).

Comment: @user I'm sorry about that, it's about a programming problem I had encountered in a problem's archive. The solution reduces to something which I can figure out in the required execution time limit if I can find a simplification for this sum in the problem. Link(s) to the problem: page 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieoyq.jpg, page 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkQGm.jpg

Answer (score 1):

**Idea.** The original vandermonde identity is a consequence of

$$ (1+x)^m (1+x) ^n = (1+x) ^{m+n}$$

(look at the coefficient of $x^r$ !!). Now we do this trick: if we want only odd $k$ to appear, we should consider $((1+x) ^m - (1-x) ^m ) /2$ (why? This is an instructive exercise). In this way we get,

$$ ((1+x) ^m - (1-x) ^m )(1+x) ^n /2 = ((1+x) ^{m+n} - (1-x)^m (1+x) ^n )/2$$

Unfortunately, I don't think this will have a closed form. Nevertheless, for $p=m+n $ in which we sum all terms we have a lucky strike. Summing up all the coefficients of a polynonial is like calculating it in 1, so that the result is $2^{m+n}$. Since you wanted to exclude $r=$0 which contributed with +1, you'll get $2^{m+n}-1$.

These techniques are based on generating functions, which I encourage you to deepen since they are a wonderful subject. Hard equalities like Vandermonde comes from very easy algebraic manipulations.

Comment: [+1] And you find back the result mentionned by Z Ahmed